# Center a Panel within a Panel, which is in a TableLayoutPanel, in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, tablelayoutpanel

So basically I've got a game board going, represented by a TableLayoutPanel. Each cell of the TableLayoutPanel represents a space on the board and contains a Panel. Each Panel has a Label in it to display what is currently in that space (e.g. a character or building) and its BackColor represents what kind of terrain that space is (e.g. Land, Water, etc.). When the player attempts to move a character, each possible space that that character can move will become "highlighted." The player will then double click one of the highlighted spaces to move the character there.

In order to highlight a space, I add a Panel to the existing Panel (the one that already has a Label in it).

So to recap, TableLayoutPanel --> Panel --> Label, Panel.

The main problem I'm having is that I can't get the "highlight-Panel" to center within its parent Panel; it's always Top-Left Centered. I want to be able to see part of the BackColor of the parent Panel in order to make it easier for the player to decide where to go. Thus, setting Dock to Fill is not an option. The highlight-Panel is slightly smaller than the parent Panel, thereby allowing for the edges of the parent Panel's BackColor to be visible. **Yes, Anchor is set to None.**

The secondary problem is that I cannot get any of the Labels' text colors to change. I've tried changing it at initialization or more directly with a specific location using "tableLayoutPanel.GetControlFromPosition(16, 4).Controls[0].ForeColor = Color.White;" but nothing seems to work.

To be honest, I'm not interested in super complicated hack fixes. But if there's something simple or something I missed, I'd really appreciate some input. Thanks.

This is the code that creates the TableLayoutPanel, the Panels within that, and the Labels within each Panel:

```
// Create TableLayoutPanel to hold Panels
tableLayoutPanel = new TableLayoutPanel()
{
    RowCount = 1,
    ColumnCount = 1,
    AutoSize = true,
    AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink,
    Location = new Point(12, 12),
    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
    AutoScroll = true,  
};

// Add tableLayoutPanel to the form
this.Controls.Add(tableLayoutPanel);

// Reset and add rows/columns + styles
tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Clear();
tableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Clear();

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    tableLayoutPanel.RowCount++;
    tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50F));
}
tableLayoutPanel.RowCount--;

for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
{
    tableLayoutPanel.ColumnCount++;
    tableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50F));
}
tableLayoutPanel.ColumnCount--;

// Add Panels to TableLayoutPanel
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        // Create new Panel
        Panel space = new Panel()
        {
            BackColor = SystemColors.ActiveCaption,
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
            Margin = new Padding(0),
            Size = new Size(45, 45)
        };

        space.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(clickOnSpace);

        // Create new Label
        Label info = new Label()
        {
            Size = new Size(93, 93),
            Text = "Info",
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
            Enabled = false,
            Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 6),
            ForeColor = Color.White
        };

        // Add Label to Panel
        space.Controls.Add(info);

        // Add Panel to TableLayoutPanel
        tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(space, j, i);
    }
}
```

And the code that creates the highlight-Panel:

```
// Highlight potential positions using possibleMoves
private void Highlight(List<Tuple<int, int>> possibleMoves, int remaining)
{
    int r = 0;
    int c = 0;

    foreach (Tuple<int, int> pair in possibleMoves)
    {
        r = pair.Item1;
        c = pair.Item2;

        // If highlight-Panel doesn't already exist
        if (tableLayoutPanel.GetControlFromPosition(c, r).Controls.Count == 1)
        {
            // Create a Panel to highlight the space
            Panel highlight = new Panel()
            {
                Name = "highlight",
                Size = new Size(30, 30),
                BackColor = Color.Yellow,
                Anchor = AnchorStyles.None
            };

            highlight.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseEventHandler(doubleClickOnSpace);

            // Add highlight Panel to space Panel
            tableLayoutPanel.GetControlFromPosition(c, r).Controls.Add(highlight);
           // Bring highlight Panel to front
            tableLayoutPanel.GetControlFromPosition(c, r).Controls[1].BringToFront();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that you could simplify your problem by creating a user control that has all the required controls in it. The highlight panel would also be there already but hidden (Opacity = 0) so you could easily show it and hide it whenever you want to. Even better would be to create a custom control where you paint the background using GDI+. That way you don't have to deal with lots of controls and can customize the look and feel very well. Windows Forms is notoriously bad in terms of performance when you have too many controls on one form.

Comment: You can always specify geometry management in terms of precise coordinates.  If panel within panel isn't doing what you want, consider using a panel within an enclosing frame.

Comment: Great advice, hankide.  The guy is having trouble using well-documented geometry management features of a packaged widget (I insist on X11 terminology, "control" being awfully generic), so recommend that he build his own widget from scratch.

Comment: I don't have a whole lot of experience using WPF so I was just trying to use what's already there instead of trying to make something from scratch. But I'll look into all that. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Take a look at the answer which is based on `Dock` despite your expectation, but it works properly. Also read the last *Note* paragraph  :)

Comment: Winforms programmers have a knack for looking too much into the toolbox or the Properties window.  Never forget the 3rd option, keeping that panel centered just takes one line of code in an event handler for the outer panel's Resize event.

Comment: Since the user said *... Thus, setting Dock to Fill is not an option.* The answer tries to show how easy `Dock` and `Padding` properties can be used to create such UI. Also about `TableLayoutPanel`, it's an alternative. In fact it's a useful alternative which let the user center a control in `TableLayoutPanel` without writing code. Getting most out of designer is not bad. Yes, handling `Resize` event is also another alternative but when there's a simple designer based solution for such task, the designer based solution is preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I actually reached a less complicated method. Instead of having a Panel within a Panel, I opted for keeping my original Panel, and creating a custom Label, which has an outside border whose thickness and color can be changed. This way I don't have to keep track of too many controls, and the CustomLabel displays everything needed.

Code for CustomLabel:

```
public class CustomLabel : Label
{
// Constructors

    // Default Constructor
    public CustomLabel() : base() { }

    public CustomLabel(bool drawBorder, int borderThickness, Color borderColor, Color textColor) : base()
    {
        if (drawBorder)
        {
            BorderThickness = borderThickness;
            BorderColor = borderColor;
        }

        Size = new Size(36, 36);
        Text = "Info";
        Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right);
        AutoSize = false;
        TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        Enabled = false;
        Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 6);
        ForeColor = TextColor;
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    }

    // Creates a border of specified thickness and color
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        if (BorderStyle == BorderStyle.FixedSingle)
        {
            int halfThickness = BorderThickness / 2;
            using (Pen p = new Pen(BorderColor, BorderThickness))
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, new Rectangle(halfThickness,
                     halfThickness,
                     ClientSize.Width - BorderThickness, ClientSize.Height - BorderThickness));
            }
        }
    }

    public int BorderThickness { get; set; }
    public Color BorderColor { get; set; }
}
```

Code for adding CustomLabel to Panels:

```
// Add Panels to TableLayoutPanel
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        // Create new Panel
        Panel space = new Panel()
        {
            Size = new Size(45, 45),
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            Margin = new Padding(0),
            ForeColor = Color.Red
        };

        space.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(MouseDownOnSpace);

        CustomLabel info = new CustomLabel(false, 0, Color.Empty, Color.Red);  // Create new CustomLabel
        space.Controls.Add(info);   // Add CustomLabel to Panel
        tlp.Controls.Add(space, j, i);      // Add Panel to TableLayoutPanel
    }
}
```

Code for adjusting the CustomLabel:

```
((CustomLabel)tlp.GetControlFromPosition(col, row).Controls[0]).BorderThickness = 6;

((CustomLabel)tlp.GetControlFromPosition(col, row).Controls[0]).BorderColor = Color.Yellow;

tlp.GetControlFromPosition(col, row).Controls[0].Text = tlp.GetControlFromPosition(col, row).Controls[0].Text;  // Transfer space information

tlp.GetControlFromPosition(col, row).Refresh();     // Refresh Panel to show changes
```

This is the end result:
(As you can see, the ForeColor still doesn't change.)

[image]

Comment: If writing graphics code is an option for you, as a good option you can use `CellPaint` event of  `TableLayoutPanel` which lets you to draw content of a cell. You can have a model  class like `Space` containing some properties representing each cell. Then using `CellPaint`, draw each cell using corresponding model information. Even better is using a  completely custom painted custom control which draws model on its surface.

Answer (score 2):

> ... Thus, setting Dock to Fill is not an option.

In fact I believe setting `Dock` to `Fill` is really a good option!

Take a look at this image. It's a `TableLayoutPanel` having 2 columns and 2 rows. And each cell contains a `Pannel` which contains a `Panel` which contains a `Label`. Despite what you expect `Dock` property of all controls has been set to `Fill`!

[image: Center a Panel in a Panel in TableLayoutPanel]

I tell you settings for the first cell which you can see `Red`, `Black` and `White` colors in it.

The cell contains:

- Red area, a `Panel` having:

  ○ `BackColor` property set to `Red`
  ○ `Margin` property set to all `0`
  ○ `Padding` property set to all `5`
  ○ `Dock` property set to `Fill`

- Black area, a `Panel` having:

  ○ `BackColor` property set to `Black`
  ○ `Margin` property set to all `0`
  ○ `Padding` property set to all `5`
  ○ `Dock` property set to `Fill`
- White label, a `Label` having:

  ○ `BackColor` property set to `White`
  ○ `Margin` property set to all `0`
  ○ `Padding` property set to all `0`
  ○ `Dock` property set to `Fill`

The structure of other cells are exactly the same, but the `BackColor` of `Label` and its parent (like the black one), to `Transparent`, so you see the `BackColor` of the most inner `Panel` (like the red one).

**Note**

The answer is completely based on setting `Dock` property to `Fill` and setting suitable `Padding` value for docked controls. But there is another elegant solution for keeping a control at center of a container automatically which is based on using a `TableLayoutPanel` having 1 row and 1 column instead of panel, and then setting `Anchor` property of child to `None`. This way the child will be centered horizontally and vertically in the `TableLayoutPanel`. You will find this post about it useful:

- [How to center a Label inside a Panel without setting Dock to Fill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39047133/3110834)

Comment: Wow, so I guess the padding is what makes it feasible? I actually opted for a less complicated option (as far as the amount of controls needed), which I'll share in a post

Comment: Yes, it's the job of `Padding`. Such answer is useful when you want to rely on controls and current features of controls. Also always using custom paint controls is an option which is useful for advanced users.